# Error 0x800F0906 while installing .Net 3.5 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework

Windows 8 comes with the .NET 4.5 framework as standard but, as part of being able to develop and deploy our applications, I need to also install the .NET 3.5 framework, so I can build applications for older versions as well as the new .NET.

However, while trying to install .Net 3.5 on Windows 8, I got the error `0x800F0906`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you installing .NET 3.5? Just install 4.5. It contains everything from 4.0 and before in addition to 4.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an item at the bottom of [this library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that details the steps you should take:

---

If installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on demand or enabling it in Control Panel fails, you may get error message 0x800f0906: "Windows couldn't connect to the Internet to download necessary files. Make sure that you're connected to the Internet, and click Retry to try again." This message may be displayed for the following reasons:

1/ Your computer is not connected to the Internet. Please connect, and then retry the operation.

If you are unable to connect your computer to the Internet, you can enable the .NET Framework 3.5 by using the installation media (ISO image or DVD) you installed Windows 8 Release Preview from. Mount the Windows 8 Release Preview installation media and type the following command from an elevated command prompt:

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:x:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

where `x:` is the drive letter for the Windows 8 Release Preview ISO image or DVD.

2/ Your administrator has configured your computer to use Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) instead of Windows Update for servicing. Please ask your administrator to enable the policy to use Windows Update instead of WSUS.

---

Comment: I'm getting this error despite being connected to the internet and not having configured WSUS. There's also no installation media provided with my PC. I asked a similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/616184/cant-install-net-framework-3-5-on-windows-8-surface-pro-error-0x800f0906-no

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same error.

My resolution is based on computers that are on a domain where **WSUS** controls the updates and doesn't have the package (in this case dotnet).

1. remove the Computer from the update policy
2. force gpo to update
3. restart Computer
4. try installing again