# Can't install .net framework 3.5 on Windows 8 (Surface Pro) error 0x800f0906, no installation media available

Tags: windows-8, installation, .net-framework, microsoft-surface

I get the same error as in this question: [Error 0x800F0906 while installing .Net 3.5 on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/435664/error-0x800f0906-while-installing-net-3-5-on-windows-8)

However the Surface Pro didn't come with installation media so I can't follow the offline installation as advised in the answer to that question.

Also not sure why this doesn't work, I can access the internet fine, can install updates OK, and can access www.update.microsoft.com.

Comment: Are you trying this on a corporate network? If yes the 2nd point in the answer there is relevant: `Your administrator has configured your computer to use Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) instead of Windows Update for servicing. Please ask your administrator to enable the policy to use Windows Update instead of WSUS.`

Comment: Thanks but it's not a duplicate (that's the same question I linked to and the answer doesn't work unless you have an iso or installation media). And no I'm not on a corporate network I'm at home and I haven't done anything with WSUS, nor do I have an administrator. I need this to run Bloomberg which gives an error on installation if 3.5 SP 1 of .net framework is not installed.

Comment: Thanks, I have deleted that 'duplicate' comment (which came up once I raised the flag) and upvoted the question.

Comment: I've downloaded a 242,743,296 byte dotnetfx35.exe installer, this just brings up a window "An app on your PC needs the following Windows feature: .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) / Install this Feature. When I click Install it says "Searching for required files" and a progress bar that loops without any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the [64Bit Windows 8 Enterprise Trial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-enterprise), mount this ISO and run the DISM command

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:x:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore if someone has an alternative?

Comment: @Jason I posted a new link

Answer (score 1):

You can also uninstall the security updates KB2966826 and KB2966828 and then install framework from the control panel/ program and features/ turn windows features on

Comment: I got this working already, but good to have another thing to try if it comes up again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be the [0x800f0906 error](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-dism-error-0x800f0906-the-source-file-could-not-be-downloaded/) is due to the updates that have not been made for your computer syste. Just go to the settings>update and security> Windows Update > Check for Update and now restart your computer.